# Apply CSS to certain part of website

Tags: html, css

I'm building a WISYWIG in which I have an iframe that needs to have content.css applied to it.

content.css: (will be applied to the iframe (src: ./content/home.php))

```
#content h4
{
    font-size:30px;
color:brown;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
text-align:center;
}
```

editpage.php: // wisywig

```
<iframe id="content" src="./content/home.php"></iframe>
```

home.php contains content that needs to be shown on the homepage of my website. As you can imagine the #content in front of my h4 is used to apply this same css to a div inside my website. However, when I apply this same css to my iframe this css wont find a #content inside the iframe. Hence my previous question.

How can I apply this CSS to both a `<div id="content">` and an iframe?

Comment: @BenM Sorry, you misunderstood me. I want the entire file just to work inside #lol without changing the content of content.css

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you're asking. This can't be achieved without changing your CSS selector. You know what the 'c' stands for in 'CSS', I assume... ;-)

Comment: give me a moment, I'm going to explain my entire situation. Its a bit complicated =P

Comment: @BenM I changed my question.

Comment: I discussed this with my teacher. We came to the conclusion that it is not possible and we should use different stylesheets for the iframe and div#content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. To apply your style to everything inside `#lol`, just use the `*` selector:

```
#lol * {
    display:inline-block;
    color:green;
}
```

If you only want **direct descendants** of `#lol`:

```
#lol > * {
    display:inline-block;
    color:green;
}
```